# Subclassing: QAbstractItemModel has no member

Tags: c++, qt, subclassing, qabstractitemmodel

I am relatively new to C++ and the Qt Framework. I tried to implement a simple QTableView with a custom model derived from QAbstractListModel.

If I call

```
model->appendRow("Test");
```

in my main application, everything works perfectly fine. However, if I call

```
table->model()->appendRow("Test");
```

I get the following build-error:

```
'class QAbstractItemModel' has no member named 'appendRow'
         table->model()->appendRow("Test");
                     ^
```

What am I missing?

### Sourcecode:

**main.c**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>
#include "exercises.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTableView *table = new QTableView();
    exercisesModel *model = new exercisesModel();
    table->setModel(model);

    model->appendRow("Test"); //why does this work...
    table->model()->appendRow("Test"); //...and this doesn't?

    table->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**exercises.h**

```
#ifndef EXERCISES_H
#define EXERCISES_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QAbstractListModel>

class exercisesModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
    exercisesModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    bool appendRow(QString data);
private:
    QList <QString> lst;

};

#endif // EXERCISES_H
```

**exercises.c**

```
#include "exercises.h"
#include <QDebug>


exercisesModel::exercisesModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractListModel(parent){
}

int exercisesModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return this->lst.size();

}

QVariant exercisesModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{
    if(this->lst.size() != 0){
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole){
            return this->lst[index.row()];
        }

        return QVariant();
    }
    return QVariant();

}

bool exercisesModel::appendRow(QString data){
    int lastElemPos = this->lst.size();
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), lastElemPos, lastElemPos);
    this->lst << data;

    endInsertRows();

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QTableView::model()` member function returns a pointer to a `QAbstractItemModel`.  That is all the compiler knows about the type at the time you call `table->model()->appendRow("Test")`.  It doesn't know that your derived model is what is actually being pointed to.  There are a few ways this could be handled.

One way is to use a cast:

```
static_cast<exercisesModel*>(table->model())->appendRow("Test")
```

Now you are explicitly telling the compiler "I know that the actual type of the object is `exercisesModel`", so it can treat it appopriately.

As noted by Kuba Ober, Qt has its own cast that will verify that the type is correct

```
qobject_cast<exercisesModel*>(table->model())->appendRow("Test")
```

This is better than `static_cast`, but this check will only be done at run-time, and the more problems you can catch during compiling, the better.

The best option may be to keep the pointer to your `exercisesModel` and use that, so there is no question about what the underlying type is.

Comment: You should also mention that the `qobject_cast<exercisesModel*>` can be used instead, allowing to verify that the object is of the correct type. This will work even if RTTI is disabled, as opposed to `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `table->model()` returns a `QAbstractItemModel`, and `QAbstractItemModel` does not have `appendRow` function you declared in `exerciseModel`, which is a child class of `QAbstractItemModel`. The compiler cannot know the actual type the `table` stored.

To access `appendRow` from `table->model()`, you need a type-casting:

```
exercisesModel *model = qobject_cast<exercisesModel *>(table->model());
// dynamic_cast could also be used.
Q_ASSERT(model);
model->appendRow("Test");
```